# Не обновляются элементы recyclerview после вызова notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Создаю адаптер и передаю класс с пустым списком:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Posts providesItemsList() {
    Posts posts = new Posts();
    posts.items = new ArrayList<>();
    return posts;
}
```

После чего идет запрос в сеть и вызывается метод адаптера:

```
public void setItems(Posts newPosts) {
    Log.i("mytag", "NewPosts items number in the setItems method: " + Integer.toString(newPosts.items.size()));
    posts.items.addAll(newPosts.items);
    Log.i("mytag", "Posts items number in the setItems method: " + Integer.toString(posts.items.size()));
    posts.profiles.addAll(newPosts.profiles);
    posts.groups.addAll(newPosts.groups);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

А вот так выглядит getItemCount:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.i("mytag", "Posts items number in the getitemcount method: " + Integer.toString(posts.items.size()));
    return posts.items.size();
}
```

И вот что пишет в логах:

```
07-15 18:57:41.967 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:41.967 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:42.005 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:42.005 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the getitemcount method: 0
07-15 18:57:42.118 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: NewPosts items number in the setItems method: 20
07-15 18:57:42.118 7481-7481/com.ovchinnikovm.android.vktop I/mytag: Posts items number in the setItems method: 20
```

Как мне правильно обновить мой recyclerview?

Comment: можно код адаптера полностью и часть кода класа где он используется?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fYyHfv4E - адаптер
https://pastebin.com/Q5zskEmm - активити
https://pastebin.com/ZAsrjHeg - модуль дагера